# Не работает z-index на fixed

Tags: html, css

Есть страница с зафиксированным блоком

[image: введите сюда описание изображения]

Как сделать, чтобы элементы были под зафиксированным блоком?
Ставил этому блоку `z-index:5`, а элементам `z-index:1` не работает.
Помогите пожалуйста.
[Ссылка на сайт](http://bot.contrust.club/bot/index.php)

Comment: z-index нужно увеличивать у блока `id="wb_Shape1"`, а у остальных убрать

Comment: @DmitryKozlov спасибо, попробую и отпишу.

Comment: @DmitryKozlov Спасибо, получилось, вопрос закрыт.

Answer (score 0):

Нужно выставить бОльший z-index (например z-index: 5) обертке самой картинки id=wb_Shape1. Тогда остальные элементы, будут под ней, как раз, что вам нужно